# Batch script not feeding command

Tags: for-loop, batch-file

I am trying to piece together a script that will read a list of servers from a file, map a drive to each of them, create a folder, copy a file to that folder, run a command and output the results to the folder, read the contents of the new file, execute a command against each of the items in the new list, and then unmap the drive.

I have the first two parts working, but when I try to read the items from the created .txt file, I cannot get the names to populate in my command.  It is ugly, but here is the script and the results (I am working from my local c:\temp folder to a remote temp folder mapped locally as z:\temp):

-----code-----

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%S in (servers.txt) do (
    net use Z: \\%%S\c$ /USER:domain\user PASSWORD
    z:
    md temp
    c:
    cd\
    cd temp
    copy sdelete.exe z:\temp
    wmic /NODE:"%%S" logicaldisk get name > z:\temp\disks.txt
)

for /F "tokens=*" %%D in (z:\temp\disks.txt) do (
    psexec.exe \\%%S c:\temp\sdelete -z %%D
)

c:  
cd temp
net use z: /delete /y
```

-----end code-----

The file gets created, but the result for the last part is echoed as:
C:\Temp>for /F "tokens=*" %D in (z:\temp\disks.txt) do (psexec.exe \%S c:\temp\
sdelete -z %D )

As a neophyte, any help would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: mfm4aa's response appears to be correct. The point is that the `metavariable` (like %%S) is only valid within the `FOR` loop that created it. Once the loop ends, its value disappears.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

instead of

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%D in (z:\temp\disks.txt) do (
```

try

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%D in ('type z:\temp\disks.txt') do (
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! That resolved the drive letter not populating issue, but I still do not get the server name over from the first part of the script:  C:\Temp>(psexec.exe \\%S c:\temp\sdelete -z C:     )
Couldn't access %S:
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks!  I used a combination of this and the other answer to get it to work.  Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%S in (servers.txt) do (
net use Z: \\%%S\c$ /USER:domain\user PASSWORD
z:
md temp
c:
cd\
cd temp
copy sdelete.exe z:\temp
wmic /NODE:"%%S" logicaldisk get name > z:\temp\disks.txt


for /F "tokens=*" %%D in (z:\temp\disks.txt) do (
psexec.exe \\%%S c:\temp\sdelete -z %%D
)
)

c:  
cd temp
net use z: /delete /y
```

Comment: Excellent!  I ended up using this, but I still needed the answer above as well for the syntax change after %%D.  Thanks!